# How do I find and eliminate an unwanted entry in my Eclipse classpath?

Tags: eclipse, classpath

Our source code repository has an Eclipse run configuration in .settings/Program.launch, a classpath configuration in .classpath, and a set of user libraries we were all directed to import months ago by the Eclipse expert who used to be in our office.  The user library set includes a defined user library named JBoss6.0.0.Final that points to all or most of the jars inside of JBoss, and the Program.launch run configuration includes this JBoss6.0.0.Final user library.

I'm now getting a conflict from slf4j telling me I need to remove one of the slf4j binding jars in my classpath:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/workspace/project/core/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/client/slf4j-jboss-logging.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

I understand why I'm getting this warning, and I want to fix the situation by taking slf4j-jboss-logging.jar out of the classpath for Program.launch .  I went to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries, I opened the JBoss6.0.0.Final user library, and I removed slf4j-jboss-logging.jar .  But when I run, I still get the same warning.

What is including this jar in my classpath?  I want to remove it.

I exported my user libraries to an XML file and searched through it and slf4j-jboss-logging.jar is not in there at all.  I read the Project.launch file and it doesn't refer to this jar.  The .classpath file does not reference this jar, but it does include the following line, which I think pulls in the JBoss6.0.0.Final user library:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/JBoss6.0.0.Final"/>
```

I looked at the classpath tab under the run configurations for Project.launch, and it appears to be showing everything defined by the .classpath file.

Where is this offending jar coming from in my classpath?

I'm running Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: Wild guess, but try restarting eclipse

Comment: @hbtest, tried that. :)  I should've put that in the post.

Comment: Is your project dependent upon another project?  Maybe if you attached the full of the .classpath file we can find the entry that's tipping you over.  Alternatively, delete the Debug Configuration that is giving you trouble and let eclipse recreate it

Answer (score 1):

Try using `jboss-classloading.xml`, this should allow you to isolate your jars from those in included in jboss.
See if this [link](http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/) helps.